# C++ - Return in Recursion of Tree

Tags: c++, class, recursion

```
class Person {
private:
    char* name;
    int numChildren;
    Person** childrenList;
public:
    Person(char* name);
    ~Person();
    // member functions
        // ...
};
```

> Suppose I create a `Person` by this code: `Person* me = new Person("Alex");`, `Alex`'s descendants' object will also be created. For a specific instance, the structure will be like this: [image]

I'd like to implement a function `const Person* Person::findPerson(const Person* thisPerson, const char* target_name) const;`, that searches through all `Person` to find the one with `name` equals `target_name`.
Here is my code:

```
const Person* Person::findPerson(const Person* thisPerson, const char* target_name) const {
    if (strcmp(thisPerson->name(), target_name) == 0)
        return thisPerson;
    for (int i = 0; i < thisPerson->numChildren(); i++)
        findPerson(thisPerson->childrenList[i], target_name);
}
```

I think the code will work but the compiler thinks it might returns nothing and don't let me compile it. And also, I don't know how to return `nullptr` if nobody is found.

Comment: In the 2nd loop, `if (findPerson(...)) return findPerson(....)`. You also need to `return nullptr` if not found.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Do you mean add a loop or modify the existing loop?

Comment: The most important thing about recursion is that recursive functions work exactly like non-recursive functions. If you called any other function than `findPerson`, what would the function return?

Comment: What do you think this function will return if the `if` statement is false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to:

1. `return` the result of the recursive call, if successful
2. `return nullptr` if the person is not found

```
const Person* Person::findPerson(const Person* thisPerson, const char* target_name) const {
    if (strcmp(thisPerson->name(), target_name) == 0)
        return thisPerson;
    for (int i = 0; i < thisPerson->numChildren(); i++) {
        const Person *p = findPerson(thisPerson->childrenList[i], target_name);
        // Found in child tree? Return it (terminate recursion)
        if (p) return p;
    }
    // Not found in this branch of the tree
    return nullptr;
}
```

Although it seems a bit odd to pass a `Person` pointer to a `Person` member function. Also, `numChildren` and `name` are member variables, not functions.

Shouldn't it be:

```
const Person* Person::findPerson(const char* target_name) const {
    if (strcmp(name, target_name) == 0)
        return this;
    for (int i = 0; i < numChildren; i++) {
        const Person *p = childrenList[i]->findPerson(target_name);
        // Found in child tree? Return it (terminate recursion)
        if (p) return p;
    }
    // Not found in this branch of the tree
    return nullptr;
}
```

And, I am obliged to ask why you are not using `std::vector` and `std::string` instead of arrays and char pointers?

Comment: but I think I need a parameter so that I can make the `this` points to `Person` other than `Alex`? Would't it always points to the first one if there is no `Person*` parameter?

Comment: for the reason using dynamic objects, this question is  simplified from a question from homework and I'm not allowed to modify the class definition.

Comment: You most likely have a root `Person` object that is at the top of the tree. You would call this function on that: `root.findPerson("blah");`. Also, if you have any instance of the `Person` class, you can call the function on that. For example, assume `john` is a `Person` object somewhere in the tree. You can search just john's descendants with `john.findPerson("blah");`

Comment: Note: I had a mistake in the 2nd code block that I just fixed.

Comment: Argh. Another one. I didn't notice `childrenList` is an array of pointers. It's almost lunch time....

Comment: nvm I got the idea. Thanks a lot!